# Visit Visa Refused for Mum, Wrong Decision, terrible wording. Pls help

Tags: visas, visa-refusals

This is a decision my mum got for her visa refusal based on failure to meet UK visa rules paragraph 4.2 appendix 4.2 a,c,e

> I am aware that you have previously applied for and been refused a visa to travel to the UK".

*This is a lie because my mum has NEVER applied for a visa to the UK before.*

Insufficient funds even though my wife and I provided our employment contracts which shows a combined income of almost 98000 pounds. My wife will be changing employers so we put contract her from current employer and future employer with new BRP which becomes active from the 4th of next month. The case officer wrote

> You also state that your daughter in law will work with (name of firm) from 4th Sept however it's unclear from document you have provided if she is currently in employment". As evidence of your sons ability to fund your strip, you have provided Barclays bank statement ending *** with balance 560 pounds. I am therefore not satisfied that you have access to sufficient funds to cover your cost of the trip.
>
> You have stated that you are self employed and that your monthly income is ****. The documents you have provided do not show that you are in employed and in receipt of income you say.

The letter then goes on to say I am refusing your visa because I am not convinced you will return home even though she has been Australia on numerous occasions and has always abided by visa conditions.

My mum is a trader in a village in Ghana and has no registered business name which she told them in the comment section of her application.

I get the feeling my wife's employment contract  and salary was not even considered. If the ECO's assertion re her not being in employment, that will be a violation of her visa and she will have leave the country.

We provided everything from my mum's property in Ghana, letter from her church, birth certificate of my siblings, our employment contract showing combined incomes, etc.

My question is, how do I address these concerns?

Comment: Can you upload a full copy of the refusal letter (with personal information blacked out)? We have [some instructions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4089/how-do-i-upload-an-image/4090#4090) on the process if you get stuck.

Comment: Marking as a duplicate for V 4.2 (a+c+e). Please see the linked material and shout if you disagree that your question has not been answered, or alternatively upload a redacted scan of your mother's notice. thanks.